# Cannot route my page from main page to show route

Tags: node.js, express

//THIS IS NOT WORKING PLEASE HELP
app.get("/dishes/:id", function(req, res){

```
dishes.findById(req.params.id, function(err, founddishes){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        // Render show template with that campground
        res.render("show", {dishes: founddishes});
    }
});
```

});

Comment: what does it mean "not working"? Do you get an error? also did you check that req.params.id is populated?

Comment: Can you please post small complete example, which also has the same issue. It would be easier to help

Answer (score 0):

Though you are not defined whats error happening with your code. Please check your router again, you can use this snipet for best practice thank you

```
dishes.findById(req.params.id)
.then((founddishes) => {
  if(founddishes){
    res.render("show", {dishes: founddishes});
  } else {
    throw[{msg: "Not found"}]
  }
})
.catch((errors) => {
  console.log(errors);
})
```